# nodejs - change contents of zip file without re-generating the whole archive

Tags: node.js, file, zip

I'm using node-zip (which uses JSZip under the hood). I need to modify the contents of a zip file, and I'd love to be able to modify it without generating the entire zip again, because it can take a long time for large archives. Here's an example:

```
var zip = new JSZip()

// Add some files to the zip
zip.file('file1', "file 1 contents\n")
zip.file('file2', "file 2 contents\n")
zip.file('file3', "file 3 contents\n")

// Generate the zip file
buffer = zip.generate()

// Make some changes
zip.file('file1', "changed file contents\n")

// Now I have to generate the entire zip again to get the buffer
buffer = zip.generate()
```

How can I do something like

```
updatedBuffer = zip.updateFile(buffer, 'file1', 'changed file contents\n')
```

Where I get an updated archive buffer but I only have to spend CPU cycles updating the one file

Answer (score 3):

Assuming JSZip v2 here (`zip.generate()`):

You can get the buffer with `asNodeBuffer()`, modify it and update the content for your file:

```
var buffer = zip.file("file1").asNodeBuffer();
// change buffer
zip.file("file1", buffer);
```

*Edit:* if you mean editing in place a zip file stored on disk: no, JSZip can't do that.

Comment: But will the second call to file() serialize the changes out to disk? My understanding is that they won't, and I'll still have to call generate() again.

Comment: You need to call `generate()` again, but JSZip will reuse the compressed content for other files (assuming you use the same compression, `STORE` or `DEFLATE`).